# how to authenticate user in web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, authentication

Please tell me how can we authenticate user in web services like i want that a user with valid id and password should only be able to consume my web service.

i am using .net framework 2.0
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom soap header for this. Have a look at this [Authenticate .NET Web Service with Custom SOAP Header](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/SOAPHeaderAuthentication.aspx)